# Opening folders in IE8 in the same window

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have encountered a problem that I have never seen before. Usually, when I tried to surf through my folders in IE, it always worked for me, and if I put various directory links inside of, I am able to go back and forth and check out all of them.

Example: I have 1 .html file. When you open it, it show 4 links to 4 directories on my desktop. When I click them, it opens that directory in the same window, and I can click back to check out the other directories too.

This worked fine in IE6 and IE7, but in IE8, a new window opens up, and there is nothing I can do.

Just a simple example:

```
<BODY>
<a href="c:\temp" >same window </a>
</BODY>
```

Usually, anything similar to that always did the trick, but not anymore. I have tried target="_self" tags, and still nothing.

Is there a way I can fix this WITHOUT tampering with the registry or running it as Admin, because I saw several solutions like that.

Thanks :)

Comment: How about <a href="file:///C:\temp" target="_self">same window</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I researched, it is a known feature that was omitted for this version, so you can't open it in the same window. Several solutions, such as registry manipulations have been suggested, but none of them worked for me. As said, it works in IE6/7 and I heard (not tried), that it is back in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

in IE go to options, general, tabs, setting, change 'when a pop-up is encountered' to new window

Comment: That is completely irrelevant to my question.

Comment: in what way? you hvae upgraded your browser and the expected function of clicking on a link has changed, this is the setting that controls how opening links works in IE8.  if i have missunderstood your question please can you calrify it for me.